# Less compiler error: variable @btn-border-radius-base is undefined

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, less, undefined, compiler-warnings

Hey there I'm new to Meteor. I have cloned an application from git and I'm trying to get it up and running locally, but I get the error:

```
=> Errors prevented startup:                  

While building the application:
client/lib/custom.bootstrap.less:2046:102: Less compiler error: variable @btn-border-radius-base is undefined

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

I have no experience with the Less compiler. When checking out that line for errors, I don't see anything that is obviously wrong with it.

```
.btn {
display: inline-block;
margin-bottom: 0; // For input.btn
font-weight: @btn-font-weight;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
touch-action: manipulation;
cursor: pointer;
background-image: none; // Reset unusual Firefox-on-Android default   style; see https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/issues/214
border: 1px solid transparent;
white-space: nowrap;
.button-size(@padding-base-vertical; @padding-base-horizontal; @font-size-base; @line-height-base; @btn-border-radius-base);
.user-select(none);
```

The code above is just a snippet within my custom.bootstrap.less file, so it does close itself properly. Thank you for the help.

Comment: The error message seems to be reasonably clear. Where is `@btn-border-radius-base` variable being set within your code? Are you importing any other files before?

Comment: @Harry yeah, sorry still pretty new to this. And its a git repo that I cloned. That variable is part of bootstrap, but I don't understand why that would be the only variable undefined, if all the other bootstrap variables aren't throwing errors.

Comment: Less does lazy loading of variables and so it kind of stops at the last variable from the last that it can't find. If you set a value for the last then the next one that is preceding it and is not set should get reported in the error. (Actually in http://less2css.org it happens the other way around for mixin calls, but Less does give only one error at any time and when it encounters one it stops there. The next error is shown only when that is fixed.). Try setting some value for this field and see what happens.